# Extracting items to separate lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to extract specific strings into separate lists.

If my input is of the form `[a1, a2, a3] [b1, b2, b3] [c1, c2, c3, c4]`, my output should have a list consisting of only the first element from each set and another list with remaining elements from list.

```
output_list_1 = [[a1] [b1] [c1]]
output_list_2 = [[a2, a3] [b2, b3] [c2,c3,c4]]
```

I was able to extract `output_list_1` with

```
output_list_1 = re.findall( r'\[(?=([a-z0-9.]+))',str(input_list))
```

How do I extract `output_list_2`?

Comment: To be clear, `[a1, a2...]` is a string that you want to parse and then make into a list and split it as you mentioned?

Comment: What is `input_list`? If it is a list, there are easier ways to do this than regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> q=[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
>>> out = [[list[0] for list in q],[list[1:] for list in q]]
```

Comment: Not a bad solution. I'd recommend choosing a word other than `list` as it shadows a Python built-in function.

Answer (score 1):

don't convert `input_list` to string

```
input_list = [[a1, a2, a3] [b1, b2, b3] [c1, c2, c3, c4]]
output_list1 = [sublist[0] for sublist in input_list]
output_list2 = [sublist[1:] for sublist in input_list]
```

---

this might be a better way to do what you want in a broader sense

```
output_list = [(sublist[0], sublist[1:]) for sublist in q]
```

in this case, iterating over `output_list` will look like this

```
for first, rest b in output_list:
    print first, rest
```

this prints `a1, [a2, a3]` etc.

Comment: Input thas coming in is already a string. So list indexing doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Oh, I see, my bad. You can use eval to get python to parse the string for you, `input_list = eval(list_string)`. You'd need to change your input to be valid python code. Only use this is if you're just writing a script for personal use and not using this in any environment where you're getting input from a user.

Comment: It might not be a good idea for performance reasons to iterate over the list twice as in the first example.